# How do I write a raptor flowchart that searches a string for a digit and once found returns a true statement

Tags: flowchart

I tried to the Is_Number command but either I am implementing it wrong or I am applying improperly.
Here is what I have so far. 
Any ideas on how to proseed would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use **to_ascii()** function.

Example:

```
x="string"    
//loop starts here
x=to_ascii(x[i])    //i=counter of your loop, if i=1 it converts "s" to ascii code
if: x>=48 && x<=57  //ascii numbers for 0-9 start at 48 and end at 57
return true;
//loop ends here
```

actual thing:
[image]

Output:
[image]

Comment: That makes sense, I was using the wrong process to locate the number thank you for your help.